# time conversion zendframework integer to time php

Tags: php, zend-framework, time

i have time in a format of an integer example:(454 seconds) and i need to convert it to a time format example:(00:07:34) any function can help me to do this??

Comment: i found a solution to my question i took this function that i found i used it and if someone still have a already exists function in the php please reference it. 


    public function sec_to_time($seconds) {
        $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $minutes = floor($seconds % 3600 / 60);
        $seconds = $seconds % 60;

        return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Zend_Date:

```
$time = new Zend_Date();
$time->setTime('00:00:00');
$time->addSecond(454);
echo $time->toString('HH:mm:ss'); // result 00:07:34
```